# how to change input-text backround-image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's that placeholder event based on select-dropdown:

```
$('#A').change(function () {
    var k = $(this).val();
    if (k == 1) {
         $("#B_input-text").attr("placeholder", "this").placeholder();
    }else if (k == 2) {
        $("#B_input-text").attr("placeholder", "this too").placeholder();
```

This changes placeholders based on some `#B` select menu.
My question is, how do i make these change `backround-image`?

Please note, this is not a div, but an input-text tag.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **[css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** function.

```
$("#B_input-text")
.attr("placeholder", "this")
.placeholder()
.css('backgroundImage', 'url("path/to/image/here")');
```

---

```
$("#B_input-text")
.attr("placeholder", "this too")
.placeholder()
.css('backgroundImage', 'url("path/to/image/here")');
```

---

You just need to pass a object with your desired css properies it it.

```
var backgroundCss = {
    'backgroundImage': 'url("path/to/image/here")',
    'backgroundRepeat': 'no-repeat',
    'backgroundPosition': '50% 50%',
  };
$("#B_input-text").css(backgroundCss);
```

Comment: Would you please expatiate that with jquery

Comment: Ok that does something, but just takes out the default backround but doesn't show a new one, and another thing is that how will one control things like size and repeat?

Answer (score 0):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Kve8L/1/

Create css class for new background, and use jquery `removeClass` and `addClass`

You can add in any other properties in the class.

```
$('#A').change(function () {
    var k = $(this).val();
    if (k == 1) {
        $("input#B_input-text")
            .removeClass('old_bg').addClass('new_bg')
            .attr("placeholder", "I am blue background image and other background properties").placeholder();

    } else if (k == 2) {
        $("input#B_input-text")
            .removeClass('new_bg').addClass('old_bg')
            .attr("placeholder", "this too").placeholder();
    }
});
```